# GCD timer handler executed before dispatch time interval

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using GCD timer to calculate time.

```
_timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, dispatch_get_main_queue());
dispatch_source_set_timer(_timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 0);
WEAKSELF
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(_timer, ^{
    [weakSelf hideView];
    if (![APP_WINDOW.subviews containsObject:self]) {
        dispatch_source_cancel(_timer);
    }
});

dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(_timer, ^{
    NSLog(@"dispatch_source_t canceled");
});

dispatch_resume(_timer);
```

As you see, the time interval is 2 sec.
but when I execute this code, the event handler will execute right now.that mean the setting of time interval hasn't work.

so the question is why the timing did not meet the requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ensure that your GCD timer is working properly

and then to determine the GCD processing code

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_source_t timer;


int count = 0;


dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();


self.timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);


// dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC) 
dispatch_time_t start = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
uint64_t interval = (uint64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timer, start, interval, 0);


dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.timer, ^{
    NSLog(@"------------%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    count++;

    if (count == 4) {

        dispatch_cancel(self.timer);
        self.timer = nil;
    }
});


dispatch_resume(self.timer);
```